# jQuery: How can i filter Elements with a specific number of children

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, filtering

I have the following Situation:

On my website I have some elements with nearly the same architecture. The only difference between them is the number of children.

And I want to get the elements with class attribute 'XY' and TWO children. The element with THREE children have to be filtered out.

How can I do this using jQuery?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Here is some HTML for you!

This is one of the elements I want to have:

```
<g class="gbox" rel="242">
    <path id="p012010-0" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.850" class="stroke" d="M228.199,318.106 L259.401,318.106 L259.401,289.226 L228.199,289.226 L228.199,318.106  Z" style="fill: #ebe8c8;"></path>
    <text id="t012010-0" x="243.80" y="312.58" ix="228.62" iy="289.65" class="box" fill="#000000" editable="true" solution="5d">K</text>
</g>
```

This is one that has to be filtered out:

```
<g class="gbox" rel="245">
    <path id="p015010-0" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.850" class="stroke" d="M321.805,318.106 L424.772,318.106 L424.772,289.226 L321.805,289.226 L321.805,318.106  Z"></path>
    <g fill="#000000" stroke="none" transform="matrix(1.200 -0.000 -0.000 1.200 0 0)"><use xlink:href="#2ca9a4d0" x="273.741" y="256.625"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#2c9d4c70" x="281.147" y="256.625"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#2c9d4db8" x="288.928" y="256.625"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#2ca9cc88" x="294.866" y="256.625"></use>
    </g>
    <text id="t015010-0" x="373.29" y="312.58" ix="322.23" iy="289.65" class="box" fill="#000000" editable="true" solution="39"> </text>
</g>
```

Comment: Can you put some sample code to elaborate the question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var $child2 = $('.XY').filter(function(){
    return $(this).children().length == 2
})
```